# Local notifications are not fired on iPad sometimes

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, notifications, uilocalnotification

Is there any difference, in the approach of firing local notification on iPhone and iPad?

In my application, local notifications are not fired on iPad sometimes, but never miss on iPhone (identical notifications on both).

I scheduled about 50 local notifications for the next 48 hours. Then I can see notification pops up on both devices at the same time, but 1 of 20 notifications does not appear on iPad, and the next notification pops up correctly again.

What could be the root cause of this issue?

**Tested on devices:**

iPhone 7 - iOS 11.1.2

iPad Air - iOS 11.2.2
iPad Pro 12.9 - iOS 11.2.5

Comment: I'm interested in this as well. I have a user of one of my apps and he keeps saying he gets some local notifications but not all but I can't find any reason for the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's your case, but, are you cancelling all the scheduled local notifications before schedulling the new 50-pack?
I recently had the same issue. In my App, at launch, I first cancel all schedulled local notifications, and after that I Schedule a bunch of them (up to 50). The problem I had was that cancelling was executing asynchronously, so the new notifications were schedulled WHILE a diferent thread was cancelling them.
The funny thing is that in some devices this was not a problem, but in other devices some local notifications seemed to "disapear". I assume this must be related to the speed of each device.
The fixing for this issue, in my case, was easy: the code that schedules the new notifications has to be executed as a completion block in the method that cancels the old ones.
Hope this helps you.